# SQLite3 and Ruby - uninitialised constant SQLite3 ... API

Tags: ruby, netbeans, sqlite

I am using Ruby on Rails in NetBeans 6.7.1 under windows, and I'm trying to use SQLite3.

I've installed the windows version of sqlite3-ruby, and I've placed sqlite3.def, sqlite3.dll and sqlite3.exe in NetBeans6.7.1>ruby2>jruby-1.2.0>bin

When I try to run the db:create rake task, I get the error and trace shown below.

Can anyone help please?

```
uninitialized constant SQLite3::Driver::Native::Driver::API
C:/Program Files/NetBeans 6.7.1/ruby2/jruby-1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:105:in `const_missing'
C:/RubyGemsFolder/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.2.5-x86-mswin32/lib/sqlite3/driver/native/driver.rb:76:in `open'
C:/RubyGemsFolder/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.2.5-x86-mswin32/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:76:in `initialize'
C:/Program Files/NetBeans 6.7.1/ruby2/jruby-1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:13:in `sqlite3_connection'
C:/Program Files/NetBeans 6.7.1/ruby2/jruby-1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:223:in `new_connection'
C:/Program Files/NetBeans 6.7.1/ruby2/jruby-1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:245:in `checkout_new_connection'
C:/Program Files/NetBeans 6.7.1/ruby2/jruby-1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:188:in `checkout'
C:/Program Files/NetBeans 6.7.1/ruby2/jruby-1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:184:in `loop'
C:/Program Files/NetBeans 6.7.1/ruby2/jruby-1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:184:in `checkout'
C:/Program Files/NetBeans 6.7.1/ruby2/jruby-1.2.0/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:191:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/Program Files/NetBeans 6.7.1/ruby2/jruby-1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:183:in `checkout'
C:/Program Files/NetBeans 6.7.1/ruby2/jruby-1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:98:in `connection'
C:/Program Files/NetBeans 6.7.1/ruby2/jruby-1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:326:in `retrieve_connection'
C:/Program Files/NetBeans 6.7.1/ruby2/jruby-1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:123:in `retrieve_connection'
C:/Program Files/NetBeans 6.7.1/ruby2/jruby-1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:115:in `connection'
C:/Program Files/NetBeans 6.7.1/ruby2/jruby-1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/tasks/databases.rake:43:in `create_database'
C:/Program Files/NetBeans 6.7.1/ruby2/jruby-1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/tasks/databases.rake:31
C:/Program Files/NetBeans 6.7.1/ruby2/jruby-1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:617:in `call'
C:/Program Files/NetBeans 6.7.1/ruby2/jruby-1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:617:in `execute'
C:/Program Files/NetBeans 6.7.1/ruby2/jruby-1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:612:in `each'
C:/Program Files/NetBeans 6.7.1/ruby2/jruby-1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:612:in `execute'
C:/Program Files/NetBeans 6.7.1/ruby2/jruby-1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:578:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Program Files/NetBeans 6.7.1/ruby2/jruby-1.2.0/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:191:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/Program Files/NetBeans 6.7.1/ruby2/jruby-1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:571:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Program Files/NetBeans 6.7.1/ruby2/jruby-1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:564:in `invoke'
C:/Program Files/NetBeans 6.7.1/ruby2/jruby-1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:2019:in `invoke_task'
C:/Program Files/NetBeans 6.7.1/ruby2/jruby-1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:1997:in `top_level'
C:/Program Files/NetBeans 6.7.1/ruby2/jruby-1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:1997:in `each'
C:/Program Files/NetBeans 6.7.1/ruby2/jruby-1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:1997:in `top_level'
C:/Program Files/NetBeans 6.7.1/ruby2/jruby-1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:2036:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Program Files/NetBeans 6.7.1/ruby2/jruby-1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:1991:in `top_level'
C:/Program Files/NetBeans 6.7.1/ruby2/jruby-1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:1970:in `run'
C:/Program Files/NetBeans 6.7.1/ruby2/jruby-1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:2036:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Program Files/NetBeans 6.7.1/ruby2/jruby-1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/lib/rake.rb:1967:in `run'
C:/Program Files/NetBeans 6.7.1/ruby2/jruby-1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/bin/rake:31
C:/Program Files/NetBeans 6.7.1/ruby2/jruby-1.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3/bin/rake:19:in `load'
C:\Program Files\NetBeans 6.7.1\ruby2\jruby-1.2.0\bin\rake:19
Couldn't create database for {"pool"=>5, "adapter"=>"sqlite3", "database"=>"db/development.sqlite3", "timeout"=>5000}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also change the database adapter you are using to the jdbc-sqlite3 one by installing the jdbc equivalents(`jdbc-sqlite3` `activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter`), which you should be able to do from [netbeans gem manager](http://wiki.netbeans.org/RubyGems#Installing_Gems_From_the_IDE)

Answer (score 1):

To date, there are different Ruby implementations, one of those is JRuby.

NetBeans bundles JRuby, which is based and powered by Java Virtual Machine (JVM).

SQLite3/Ruby bindings are not compatible with JVM, these needs the original and native Ruby implementation, also known as MRI (Matz Ruby Implementation or C Ruby).

Please install a separate Ruby version and then add the interpreter to NetBeans menu.

You can find tutorials on using newer 1.8.6 or 1.9.1 with Rails [here](http://blog.mmediasys.com/2009/07/06/getting-started-with-rails-and-sqlite3/)

I recommend you install version 1.8.6 of the installer (Release Candidate 1) from [here](https://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=167&release_id=41267)

Hope this helps.